# Android Create XML on 3.1

Tags: android, xml, transformer-model

I am getting this error using SDK 12.

```
Caused by: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
```

Line 175 in my activity is `Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();`.

```
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864): Caused by: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at org.apache.xml.serializer.OutputPropertiesFactory.getDefaultMethodProperties(OutputPropertiesFactory.java:322)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at org.apache.xalan.templates.OutputProperties.<init>(OutputProperties.java:83)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.<init>(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:88)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:823)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at jpl.test.AndroidserverActivity.generateXML(AndroidserverActivity.java:175)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at jpl.test.AndroidserverActivity$GetXML.doInBackground(AndroidserverActivity.java:63)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at jpl.test.AndroidserverActivity$GetXML.doInBackground(AndroidserverActivity.java:1)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
07-18 10:32:41.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12864):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidserverActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GetXML xml = new GetXML();
        xml.execute();
    }

    private class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
    {
        protected String doInBackground(String... conn) 
        {
            String UID = "iPAD-CN5-DSS25-AC25";
            try 
            {
                String xml = generateXML("AC25", "/fa/gdscc/dss25-apc", UID);
                if (send("localhost", xml))
                    getData(UID);
                else
                    System.out.println("False");
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String generateXML(String conn, String funcAddr, String UID) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
                                                                    IOException, XPathExpressionException, TransformerException 
    {   
        String url = getXML("0", conn);

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = XMLfromString(url);

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/SubscrProf/DataItem/DataItemName");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        //build xml
        Document output = builder.newDocument();

        //create root
        org.w3c.dom.Element root = output.createElement("JMSMON2Req");
        output.appendChild(root);

        //create subitem
        org.w3c.dom.Element subItemNode = output.createElement("SubItem");
        subItemNode.setAttribute("UID", UID);
        root.appendChild(subItemNode);

        //create funcAddr
        org.w3c.dom.Element funcAddrNode = output.createElement("FuncAddr");
        Text text = output.createTextNode(funcAddr);
        funcAddrNode.appendChild(text);
        subItemNode.appendChild(funcAddrNode);

        //create itemname
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            org.w3c.dom.Element itemNameNode = output.createElement("ItemName");
            text = output.createTextNode(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
            itemNameNode.appendChild(text);
            subItemNode.appendChild(itemNameNode);
        }

        //create metadata uid
        org.w3c.dom.Element metaDataNode = output.createElement("Metadata");
        metaDataNode.setAttribute("key", "UID");
        text = output.createTextNode(UID);
        metaDataNode.appendChild(text);
        subItemNode.appendChild(metaDataNode);

        //create metadata conn
        org.w3c.dom.Element metaDataNode2 = output.createElement("Metadata");
        metaDataNode2.setAttribute("key", "CONN");
        text = output.createTextNode("5");
        metaDataNode2.appendChild(text);
        subItemNode.appendChild(metaDataNode2);

        /////////////////
        //Output the XML

        //set up a transformer
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(output);

        trans.transform(source, out);

        return URLEncoder.encode("req", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sw.toString(), "UTF-8");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try sending a string parameter when calling to xml.execute();

Comment: nope, there was no change since currently, I am not using any parameters from xml.execute().